# colab module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, placeholder, generative-adversarial-network

First of all now a days I can only use Colab. :-(

I am trying to reproduce a GAN CNN. In order to build this network, i need two inputs, one for the generator and one for the discriminator. And I define this:

```
def model_inputs(dim_real, dim_z):
  real_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dim_real')
  z_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dim_z')
  return real_input, z_input
```

-Then when I later call the funtion in:

```
input_real, input_z = model_inputs(input_size, z_size)
```

-The systems says:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

Can somebody help me to understand (taking into account I use Colab )
Thanks in advance

Comment: Placeholder does not exist in TF2.x, set to TF1.x : `%tensorflow_version 1.x`